# Find python version in Tcl script

Tags: tcl

Is it possible to find out in a .tcl script, what python version is installed? In other words, how can I tell what python version is in default path from a .tcl script?

[Tcl Wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Python) doesn't include useful information about this

currently I am calling a python script which prints sys.version and parsing its output.

**.py**

```
import sys

def find_version():
    version = sys.version
    version = version.split()[0].split('.')
    version = version[0] + '.' + version[1]
    print(version)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_version()
```

**.tcl**

```
set file "C://find_python_version.py"
set output [exec python $file]
```

Comment: What's wrong with parsing the output of "python -v"?

Comment: @stolenmoment currently I am calling a python script which prints `sys.version` and parsing its output. Was wondering if there's a better method.

Comment: @TonyTannous try : `set output [exec python --version]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Python's `sys.version_info` because I can format the version string in any way I like:

```
set pythonVersion [exec python -c {import sys; print("%d.%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:3])}]
puts "Python version: $pythonVersion"
```

Output:
Python version: 2.7.15

A couple of notes:

- A Python script (in curly braces) follows the `-c` flag will print out the version in the form x.y.z, you can format it any way you like
- The value of `sys.version_info` is a list of many elements, see documentation. I am interested only in the first 3 elements, hence `sys.version_info[:3]`
- The `print` statement/function with parentheses will work with both Python 2 and Python 3

Answer (score 1):

A simple enough approach seems to be to parse the result of `python --version`:

```
proc pythonVersion {{pythonExecutable "python"}} {
    # Tricky point: Python 2.7 writes version info to stderr!
    set info [exec $pythonExecutable --version 2>@1]
    if {[regexp {^Python ([\d.]+)$} $info --> version]} {
        return $version
    }
    error "failed to parse output of $pythonExecutable --version: '$info'"
}
```

Testing on this system:

```
% pythonVersion
3.6.8
% pythonVersion python2.7
2.7.15
```

Looks OK to me.

Comment: As a bonus, it needs no helper Python script.

Comment: One concern, currently I initialize a list with `{"3.6"}` How can I turn the `3.6.8` to the same type? because appending `3.6.8` is causing script to crash later on...

Comment: @TonyTannous You could use a simple regex like `regexp -inline {^\d+\.\d+} [pythonVersion]` maybe